# Select XML Node by position

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML structure

```
<Root>
    <BundleItem>
        <Item>1</Item>
        <Item>2</Item>
        <Item>3</Item>
    </BundleItem>
    <Item>4</Item>
    <Item>5</Item>
    <Item>6</Item>
    <BundleItem>
        <Item>7</Item>
        <Item>8</Item>
        <Item>9</Item>
    </BundleItem>
</Root>
```

And by providing the following xPath

```
//Item[1]
```

I am selecting

```
<Item>1</Item>
<Item>4</Item>
<Item>7</Item>
```

My goal is to select only `<Item>1</Item>` or `<Item>7</Item>` regardless of the parent element where they are found and only depending on the position, which i am providing in the xPath.
Is it possible to do that only by using the position and without providing additional criterias in the xPath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//Item[1]` selects the all the first child elements that are `<Item/>` regardless of their parent.

To get the two items you are looking for you could use `//Item[text() = 1 or text() = 7]`.

A good tutorial can be found at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and you can play with XPath expressions over your XML input [here](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester). (I am not affiliated with either of these resources but find them useful.)

Comment: Hi @Mark, my goal is to select items regardless of the parent element where they are found. I have edited the question, thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer to get all `<Item/>` elements with text equal to "1" or "7". Is this what you are after?

Comment: Indeed, by providing some filtering or extended criterials I can access what I need, but in the real scenario, I do not have any field to filter, so the only thing that I can use for selection/filtering is the position(). I though that by calling //Item I will have all Item elements inside one collection/list and will be able to select each of them only by providing the position..but looks like it keeps them in separated lists per the parent element.. or something like that :)

Comment: hmm... I'm not entirely sure I follow. There must be some "hook" for us to encode into the XPath. If you can express that "hook" in English then I can try to translate into XPath.

Comment: I was able to solve it by changing the logic in my XSLT.. it is fine now. My bad was that I was thinking that //Item will store all Item elements inside one single list. And I started wondering is it a way basicaly store all Item elements inside one singe list regardless of the parent element (in general to avoid that "grouping" per parent element) and to select the N-th only by providing his position.. for example //Item[3]. But looks like it is not possible and I have to live with that "grouping" :)